# Сравнение объектов типа Integer Java

Tags: java, объекты, integer-overflow

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему данный код выводит в консоль 
false
true

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Integer a = 135;
        Integer b = 135;
        Integer c = 110;
        Integer d = 110;
        System.out.println(a == b);
        System.out.println(c == d);

    }
}
```

Вроде ж должны сравниваться ссылки на объекты, а они тут все разные

Answer (score 14):

*Java* по умолчанию кэширует `Integer` значения из диапазона от **-128** до **127**. Если число попадает в этот диапазон, то объект создаваться не будет, а будет взят из кэша.

В силу этого имеем, что первое сравнение даст `false`, а второе `true`.

Так же, есть возможность регулировать размер кэша, следующим параметром *jvm*:

```
-XX:AutoBoxCacheMax=<cache_max_value>
```

Или же, с

```
-Djava.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high=<cache_max_value>
```

Comment: Для int таких бубнов не получится? Везде будет true?

Comment: @Plem int это примитив, а они всегда сравниваются по значению.

Comment: Стоить добавить что этот кэш является ничем иным как пулом интернированнных значений и используется при автобоксинге дабы не создавать новые объекты.

Answer (score 0):

Все правильно.
При старте JVM, создается 128 экземпляров Integer для чисел от 0 до 127 включительно.
При раcпаковке, если значение в диапазоне от 0 до 127, переменной присваивается сгенерированная при старте JVM ссылка на экземпляр Integer. Если же присваивается значение более 127, то генерируется новый класс и его ссылка присваивается переменной.
Операция сравнения сравнивает только ссылки. Получается если число меньше 127, то ссылки ведут на один и тот же экземпляр Integer. Если больше 127, то ссылки ведут на разные экземпляры независимо от их значения. Поэтому сравнивать по значению надо всегда через equals()