# Сравнение объектов оператором == в Java. Integer vs int

Tags: java

Для сравнения объектов в `Java` используется метод `equals()`, но что если сравниваются между собой два объекта-обертки для примитивных типов:

```
Integer a = 120;
Integer b = 120;
Integer c = 130;
Integer d = 130;

System.out.println(a==b); // true
System.out.println(c==d); // false
```

Почему в первом случае возвращается `true`, а во втором `false`?

Comment: В 1 случае ссылки одинаковые, вернуло true, а во втором разные, поэтому false

Comment: Аналогичный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/692252/183458

Answer (score 7, accepted):

См. javadoc класса `Integer`, внутренний класс [`IntegerCache`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/1a3de3cdc684/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java#l780):

```
/**
 * Cache to support the object identity semantics of autoboxing for values
 * between -128 and 127 (inclusive) as required by JLS.
 *
 * The cache is initialized on first usage.  The size of the cache
 * may be controlled by the {@code -XX:AutoBoxCacheMax=<size>} option.
 * During VM initialization, java.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high property
 * may be set and saved in the private system properties in the
 * sun.misc.VM class.
 */
private static class IntegerCache {...}
```

т. е. по умолчанию кешируются значения между -128 и 127, как указано в JLS, см. [5.1.7. Boxing Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7). Если значение попадает в этот диапазон, то оно берется из кеша, если нет, то сравниваться будут объекты.

---

Размером кеша можно управлять, изменяя параметры JVM:

```
-XX:AutoBoxCacheMax=<cache_max_value>
```

либо

```
-Djava.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high=<cache_max_value>
```

Answer (score 6):

Класс `Integer` содержит кэш обёрток для значений от -128 до 127.

Если число лежит в этом диапазоне и обёртки нет в кэше, то создаётся новая обёртка и помещается в кэш для последующего использования.

Если не в диапазоне, то каждый раз создаётся новая обёртка, и при сравнении вы получите `false`, так как объекты разные.

Подробнее в исходниках метода [`valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)):

```
/**
 * Returns an {@code Integer} instance representing the specified
 * {@code int} value.  If a new {@code Integer} instance is not
 * required, this method should generally be used in preference to
 * the constructor {@link #Integer(int)}, as this method is likely
 * to yield significantly better space and time performance by
 * caching frequently requested values.
 *
 * This method will always cache values in the range -128 to 127,
 * inclusive, and may cache other values outside of this range.
 *
 * @param  i an {@code int} value.
 * @return an {@code Integer} instance representing {@code i}.
 * @since  1.5
 */
public static Integer valueOf(int i) {
    if (i >= IntegerCache.low && i <= IntegerCache.high)
        return IntegerCache.cache[i + (-IntegerCache.low)];
    return new Integer(i);
}
```

Для сравнения по значению можно привести один из объектов к примитивному типу:

```
System.out.println((int)a == b)
```

Comment: https://habr.com/post/104231/

Comment: Этот кэш не только для Integer, а для всех целочисленных типов