# Сравнение int в ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Collections.addAll(list, 127,127,128,128,2,4,4,8,8,4,12,12,14,14,128,128,128,500,500,500,500,500,-127,-127,-128,-128,-129,-129);

    for (int x = 0; x < list.size() - 1; x++) {
        if (list.get(x) != list.get(x + 1)){
            System.out.println(list.get(x) + " != " + list.get(x + 1));
        }
        if (list.get(x) == list.get(x + 1)) {
            System.out.println(list.get(x) + " == " + list.get(x + 1));
        }
    }
}
```

}

Вывод из консоли :

```
127 == 127                                                                            
127 != 128                                
128 != 128                                         
128 != 2                                  
2 != 4                                        
4 == 4                                    
4 != 8                                           
8 == 8                                                 
8 != 4                                       
4 != 12                                           
12 == 12                                                                                     
12 != 14                                                       
14 == 14                                                                  
14 != 128                                                                   
128 != 128                                                                   
128 != 128                                                                
128 != 500                                                      
500 != 500                                                         
500 != 500                                                       
500 != 500                                                 
500 != 500                                                      
500 != -127                                                         
-127 == -127                                                          
-127 != -128                                                          
-128 == -128                                                       
-128 != -129                                                       
-129 != -129
```

Доброго времени! Столкнулся с тем что при проверке на равенство все числа больше 127 и меньше - 128 проходят проверку не равно как в примере выше. Хотелось бы разобраться почему так происходит и как это исправить. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130311/weird-integer-boxing-in-java

Comment: @Alex, сравнивание объектов через `==` / `!=` выполняется по ссылкам, а не значению. И у вас все-таки сравниваются не `int`, а их обертка `Integer`, т.к. из-за особенностей коллекций java они не могут хранить простые типы, только объекты

Comment: Вопрос полезный, но дубликат. Может, стоит закрыть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не используйте сравнение объектов через ==, сравнивайте через equals.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Collections.addAll(list, 127, 127, 128, 128, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8, 4, 12, 12, 14, 14, 128, 128, 128, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, -127, -127, -128, -128, -129, -129);

        for (int x = 0; x < list.size() - 1; x++) {
            if (!list.get(x).equals(list.get(x + 1))) {
                System.out.println(list.get(x) + " != " + list.get(x + 1));
            }
            if (list.get(x).equals(list.get(x + 1))) {
                System.out.println(list.get(x) + " == " + list.get(x + 1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А еще работает если при сравнении приводить к инт (int). Вот мне интересно почему с числами в диапазоне от -128 до 127 сравнения проходили правильно. Это как то связано с классом оберткой Integer?

Comment: Это веселая фишка java - ответ тут уже давали - посмотрите по ссылке https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/692252/%d0%a1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%b0-integer-java

Comment: спасибо большое разобрался почему так происходит.